# Why my bootstrap breakpoint width differs from the standard size?

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am trying to understand bootstrap classes. The doc contains following example:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It [gets rendered as follows in the jsfiddle as follows](https://jsfiddle.net/ru6bht02/22/):

[image]
[image]

Given that [class `sm` corresponds to size `>=576px`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#grid-options), I dont get why above gets rendered with breakpoint at `593px`.

**PS:**

The CSS is as follows:

```
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.col {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
}

.col-sm {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
}
```

Comment: Your example Fiddle appears to be working as expected at the correct breakpoint values.